# Add HTML to Custom Shipping Carrier/Methods

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have been playing a little around with PrestaShop, and found it quite interesting - so I wanted to make some stuff for it.

What I have done so far is, I have created a couple of different Shipping Carriers - and now I want to add some certain HTML to the shipping page - based on the selected shipping method. But I can't quite figure out how I should do this.

If it wasn't clear what I'm looking to do is. I have created a shipping method lets say "GSL, house delivery", and when a custom picks that shipping carrier on the shipping page - I want to show some specific HTML, related to that carrier - either below it, or somewhere on the shipping page.

I cant quite figure out how I should do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question a bit; you can further edit it by clicking on the "edit" link below it. (Or use this link: [edit]). Here on Stack Overflow, we focus on objective questions. _What_ you're going to do is up to you, and is subjective. Such questions get closed here._How_ you should do something is objectively answerable. For the best results, you should include what you have tried already. This shows effort, and helps answerers to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest method would be to edit the file themes/[ theme -name]/order-carrier.tpl around line 199 , you should find:

```
{foreach $option.carrier_list as $carrier}
```

Inside that loop you can find the whole structure of the carrier page.

Add a structure like this where you want to put the html.

```
{switch $carrier.id} 
    {case 1} 
        <!-- custom html for the courier that has the id 1 -->
    {/case} 
    {case 2} 
        <!-- custom html for the courier that has the id 2 -->
    {/case} 
{/switch}
```